# How to add class to the html Img element using SharePoint style Page element

Tags: 2013, style

I have image tag in SharePoint page.

`<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">`

I'm trying to add class="ABC" to my html img tag using SharePoint Page element under style section in SharePoint ribbon.

[image]

Is it possible to add class to image tag?

so it will display like this

`<img src="smiley.gif" class="ABC" alt="Smiley face">`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Content Editor webpart you should click to Page - Edit, on Format Text tab click Edit Source, and you are free to add any html code to your page.
After adding don`t forget to click Save button on the page.

More steps on [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-HTML-code-to-a-web-page-11b48b3c-d033-41da-9ba5-d63ac0a5a47e)

If problem is about the adding code in Edit Source window - appent full page code to your question, I`ll give you more detailed advice.

Comment: I know that.
I want to create SharePoint style page element. 
When user select image --> then select custom style page element, then CSS class will get applied.
Like we apply Paragraph style.

Answer (score 1):

After you add page elements or images you can further customize the content by clicking "Edit Source" option on the ribbon. It will edit your complete content into HTML format from there you can add class.
[image]

Comment: I know that.
I want to create SharePoint style page element. 
When user select image --> then select custom style page element, then CSS class will get applied.
Like we apply Paragraph style.